# Is there any way to make a Balloon Tip never close?

Tags: c#, tooltip, balloon

My application is a monitor that may run in the background while the user is away, and its purpose is to visually alert the user when some changes have occurred. MessageBoxes seem a little obnoxious, so I figure a Balloon Tip will accomplish the task without messing with the focus in case they happen to be doing something.

Unfortunately, the thing requires a timeout parameter. I would like for it to stay indefinitely until the user closes it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/10/349894.aspx

Comment: Have you tried values of `0` or `-1` for the `Timeout` property?

Comment: @rmx I believe it has a minimum value, so setting it to anything lower will make no difference.

Comment: OK, worth a try. I seem to remember it working for me though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is already taken care of by Windows.  The timeout counter doesn't start ticking until it detects keyboard or mouse input.  From the Remarks section of NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip:

> In addition, if the user does not
>   appear to be using the computer (no
>   keyboard or mouse events are
>   occurring) then the system does not
>   count this time towards the timeout.

Comment: Oh... I didn't notice that probably because I'm actively using my keyboard and mouse while testing it. So this means I don't need to do anything extra. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to specify an infinite timeout.

That said, if you set the timeout to [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx), the tooltip will wait for 2,147,484 seconds, i.e. roughly 25 days. Chances are that your user will have noticed the tooltip by then, or that he/she never will.

**EDIT:** @Hans Passant mentions a system setting that puts an upper bound on the timeout value, so... that probably won't work after all. His answer is better anyway.

Comment: Nope, it's milliseconds.  And a system setting clips it to a maximum value, 30000 is the default afaik.

Comment: @Hans, yes, 2,147,483,647 milliseconds, i.e. 2,147,484 seconds. I did not know about the upper bound though, thanks :)